# Webservice call MVC 6 with razor vs WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, razor

This seems to be a newer topic or i haven't understood it. I have build a website using core 2.2, mvc and razor. I have my CRUD model functions in my controller class.

Now I want to call these functions from my website(which works fine) and from my **xamarin** app.

Having read lots of tutorial, the way to go is to put a webapi in between. But lots of sites indicate that mvc and webapi have merged in .net core.

What is the best practice for my **xamarin** app to communicate with my website?

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't need a web API but you cannot call your ActionResult from xamarin app. if your controllers' methods return an object instead of a view then MVC will take care of serializing it to JSON for you so this way you can call it from your app. for more information check [this article](https://stackify.com/asp-net-core-web-api-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with same methodology, I have new website and new mobile app which is built in Xamarin.

I have created a separate project in WebApis. Now I can use same Apis in both projects. So no need to write new code for separate projects. Just write simple json based Apis and use in both projects.

Comment: The MVC with EntityFramework has it all included. I'm doing the job twice , this bothers me.